# How to build muscles and lose fat quickly within weeks?

Tags: training

Some people like models or actors have to look their best for certain occasions like a shooting. They have special training programs and diets that allow them to improve their looks within several weeks to an impressive degree what I have heard.

What are they doing to achieve these results? I am not talking about long lasting or healthy measures to get in shape, I know enough about those. I wonder what one can do to boost his looks within a few weeks, aiming to look the best at a specific time, no matter what.

Comment: This is just ASKING for fad diets.

Comment: But wouldn't the average fad diets lack the necessary nutritions to build muscles? Or do you have a specific diet in mind?

Comment: Special training programs = airbrush or photoshop! :-)

Comment: What is "to an impressive degree" from what you've heard?  That's the crux of your whole question.  Give numbers if you can.

Comment: It's rarely done "within a few weeks."

Comment: @Demento Also take a look at some previous questions about ["losing fat and gaining muscle."](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/search?q=lose+fat+gain+muscle).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, You asked for it :)

Looking at this from the theory standpoint.

### Fat loss

Loosing fat in a matter of weeks is possible. That much is certain and, as Natasha mentioned, a kethogenic or hgc diet *could* do it (with a **BIG** emphasis on *could*)

### Muscle gain

Now here we get to the part where it gets complicated. A drastic fat cut means leaving out some nutrients nutrients and/or doing excessive amounts of cardio activities. Doing anyone of those means, that there is either less material for the muscles to work with, or the musscles are more fatigued to begin with, and the muscle gain, while not out of the question, will **not** be drastic.

So, in resume:

**BOTH** cutting fat drastically *and* building muscle at the same time is not viable.

The way movie stars and such do it, is by gaining muscle first, and then drastically cutting, usually by means of extensive cardio, carb depletion and the sort, which is all fine and dandy in the short run, but not healthy at all in the long run.

Answer (score 2):

Well they have personal trainers who work them out for hours a day and personal chefs that make all their food. Their bodies are a huge aspect of their job, so they have the time and money to spend all day making it the way it needs to be. Generally not possible for people who don't have access to that stuff.

If you just want a quick way to lose weight maybe try a ketogenic diet or hcg or something. You said you didnt care about whether or not it was healthy or if it lasted long so do some research.

Comment: +1: Thanks for mentioning ketogenic diet and hcg diet. I will take a look into them.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Tim Ferriss's posts: [How I Gained 34 lbs. of Muscle in 4 Weeks](http://www.fourhourworkweek.com/blog/2007/04/29/from-geek-to-freak-how-i-gained-34-lbs-of-muscle-in-4-weeks/) and [How to Lose 20 lbs. of Fat in 30 Days… Without Doing Any Exercise](http://www.fourhourworkweek.com/blog/2007/04/06/how-to-lose-20-lbs-of-fat-in-30-days-without-doing-any-exercise/).

Comment: Care to explain why we should check it out?

Comment: I hoped it would be clear from the titles of the posts that they're relevant to this question.

Comment: Its clear that they have the same topic, but not whether they are worth reading. Besides what happens if the blog you linked to goes down? Then you no longer have an answer